# UITabbar with rounded corners & custom height in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I'm using UITabbar in my application, which has four options. I wanna increase the default Jabbar height and make the top left & top right corners to be rounded one.

I tried with these solutions but its not working. [Rounded corners for UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127839/rounded-corners-for-uitabbar)

[Change tab bar height and width and add rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925733/change-tab-bar-height-and-width-and-add-rounded-corners/39926283)

Below code works fine with rounded corners and height but it's showing a black space in the corners(attached image for reference).

[image]

Below is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
       [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

       [self.tabBar invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
       CGRect tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame;
       tabFrame.size.height = tabbarHeight;
       tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - tabbarHeight;
       self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
}

// Called this method in viewDidLoad
- (void)customizeTabbarAppearance {
    [self.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.tabBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.tabBar.layer setCornerRadius:20];
    [self.tabBar setTranslucent:YES];
    [self.tabBar.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    self.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = kCALayerMinXMinYCorner | kCALayerMaxXMinYCorner;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to set background color to UIWindow?

Comment: Can you explain how changing window's bg color affects with this

Comment: I tried like this
    UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    [window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
Still I'm facing same issue

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SUITabView

Comment: @Sivagami just you set `self.window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;` on your App Delegate class.

Comment: I tried with above mentioned its not working.  Still the black space is visible

Comment: @Sivagami have you put above on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? have you try this too `UIWindow.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white()` on AppDelegate.

Comment: @Sivagami Maybe you missed to set background color to your superview of an UIViewController. Make sure this too.

Answer (score 0):

@Sivagami Try with this on your controller UIViewDidLoad,

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: Tried with this but doesn't work. But instead of changing the window color in AppDelegate I changed in initial viewcontroller all the tabs, working fine for me now.  Thanks for helping